# RMarkdown: Why do I have to reinstall all packages everytime I knit?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have the following R code in one of my RMarkdown scripts:

```
install.packages("dplyr", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages("tidyr", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
options(scipen = 999)
source("classify.r")
```

When I "knit" the Markdown to HTML with Shift+Ctrl+K, the packages are successfully installed and loaded. However, when I re-knit it, the packages are installed from scratch, every time - although I already have them, and that takes a while.

I am using RStudio.

How can I circumvent this without having to comment the respective lines?

Comment: You could include something like `if(!require(dplyr)) install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: This works, maybe you can post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since "`require` returns (invisibly) a logical indicating whether the required package is available" you can conveniently use it for programming to either load the package or, if it's not available, (try to) install it and load it afterwards. So you could modify your code along the lines of:

```
if (!require(dplyr)) {
    install.packages("dplyr")
    require(dplyr)
}
```

This should load the package if it's already available or if not, try to install it and load it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

````
```{r chunkNameHere, cache=TRUE}
install.packages("dplyr", repos="REPOLINK")
install.packages("tidyr", repos="REPOLINK")
install.packages("ggplot2", repos="REPOLINK")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
```
````

The 'cache' flag should ensure the packages aren't reinstalled each time.

Here is the output from the first time I knit:

```
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: chunkNameHere (with options) 
List of 1
 $ cache: logi TRUE



processing file: Untitled.Rmd
trying URL 'REPOLINK'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3870896 bytes (3.7 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3.7 Mb

trying URL 'REPOLINK'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 72424 bytes (70 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 70 Kb

trying URL 'REPOLINK'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2671874 bytes (2.5 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 2.5 Mb


/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc Untitled.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output Untitled.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/l2/qcrxbd0s36x7jkk4k2szc9dr0000gn/T//Rtmpcy2bZL/rmarkdown-str8c75262f5f18.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight 
output file: Untitled.knit.md


Output created: Untitled.html
```

And here it is when I run it a second time:

```
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: chunkNameHere (with options) 
List of 1
 $ cache: logi TRUE


/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc Untitled.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output Untitled.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /var/folders/l2/qcrxbd0s36x7jkk4k2szc9dr0000gn/T//Rtmp0WIDxR/rmarkdown-str8c8a542dd362.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/highlight 


processing file: Untitled.Rmd
output file: Untitled.knit.md


Output created: Untitled.html
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, they get downloaded all over again, and then installed (and compiled).

Comment: I added the outputs for the first and second time I knit, with the cache=TRUE flag. As you can see, the second time I knit "cache: logi TRUE" is returned and none of the packages are installed.

Comment: Yes, `cache: logi TRUE` is also shown in my case, but still, the packages are reinstalled. Maybe a misconfiguration in RStudio (it also always asks me to restart RStudio). Thanks for your answer, anyway.

Comment: How are you determining that the packages are being reinstalled?

Comment: Console output, just as in your first output. Sometimes (but not every time, weirdly), they are even recompiled. But honestly, I probably don't understand enough about the R package system.